# SQL Agent Job failes when trying to execute SSIS package due to some permission issues

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, active-directory, sql-server-data-tools

I deployed ssis package on sql server 2012. Thereafter scheduled a sql job to run this ssis package weekly.
When I started a job for the first time, it failed with following error.

> The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User MyDomain\MyUserName.  The
>   last step to run was step 1 (scheduling ssis package).
>
> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  2:17:12 PM 
>   Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 6, Execution
>   Status:4.  To view the details for the execution, right-click on the
>   Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report 
>   Started:  2:17:12 PM  Finished: 2:17:17 PM  Elapsed:  4.493 seconds. 
>   The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am sure there is some issue with permissions, however I am not able to resolve this.

This package is deleting a content of a folder present on my desktop.
SQL Server instance is running on my machine. I am on a standalone machine.

Answer (score 20):

After searching lot of articles I got an article which helped me identifying actual error :-
Identifying issue

1. Login sql server instance
2. Navigate to Integration Service Catalogs
3. Right Click on your SSISDB catalog and select All Reports -> Standard reports -> All Executions
4. For your folder, click on All Messages for failed task
5. Here you will see your error

In my case error was "Access to path 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Test Folder' is denied". To note there is a section Caller in this report who is trying to access this folder, in my case it was **NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT**.

Go to this folder, right click -> Properties -> Security
Under Group/username click Edit -> Inside new pop up Add new user
Now if you are trying to find NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT user, you won't find since its under a service account which means you will see a user named **SERVICE** . This is the user you need to add to this folder.

As soon as I added this, my job started running :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case 
Identifying issue:
Login sql server instance
Navigate to Integration Service Catalogs
Right Click on your SSISDB catalog and select All Reports -> Standard reports -> All Executions
-check the fail/ red error log report section(overview,all messages,execution performance)
- I went to overview ->clicked execution path -> under error messages clicked view context
this will show you step by step execution. I had a data type mismatch as I reran the sql script in ssms it was giving issue. Once I fixed the data type or removed extra data.
All back to normal

Comment: How is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
I got the same error in SQL agent job ,so I just check SSIS package whether it is running or not then find that package is failing because from proc we are taking input as string and in package I have create a variable datatype object to store the proc input ,When I changed that my SSIS package as well as sql job is running fine now.
I hope this will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while executing the SSIS Job in SQL Agent "Access to the path 'C:\Users\abhis\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SSIS\AWS-S3-FileLoad\OracleEmployeeDetails' is denied.".

**Solution** -

**Go to this folder for which you are getting the Access Denied Error,**

1. Go to Folder -> Properties -> Security -> To Change Permission Click
   Edit - > Add the user "SERVICE" to the Folder.

\As soon as the "SERVICE" user has been added, Job has executed and completed successfully.\