# SSIS package execution failed on one package, but not the other one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssis

My SSIS project, developed in Visual Studio 2012 under my Windows user account, includes two packages, SendMailOnly.dtsx and SendMailWithAttachment.dtsx. Both uses a Script Task to send out an email. The first one has no attachment, and the second one attached a file from a network folder. Both packages run fine in my development environment. The project is then deployed to SQL Server Integration Service Catalogs, on a network SQL Server. From there, the package is called through a job in SQL Server Agent using my windows account. The first package is executed successfully, but the second one failed. The error message stats that

> > "Script Task Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
public void Main() 
{   
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(); 
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
message.From = new MailAddress("email@mydomain.com"); 
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail@mydomain.com")); 
message.Subject = "SSIS Email"; 
message.Body = "email with attachment"; 
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName)); 
}
```

Comment: Have you select Read-Only variable for attachment in Script Task Editor?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I did not use any variables in this package, but I do plan to use some variables in other packages. My script code:

Comment: <code>public void Main()
{         MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                message.From = new MailAddress("email@mydomain.com");
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail@mydomain.com"));
                message.Subject = "SSIS Email";
                message.Body = "email with attachment";
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName));
} </code>

Comment: As already mentioned this is almost definitely a service account issue. Either you are using a mapped drive which doesn't exist for the service account or the service account doesn't have access to the UNC

Comment: I have added your code to your question. In future please add your code first or edit your question to add it later. Also, I don't understand why you would ignore all the suggestions about this being a security issue? If you run @Kinchit's code below you will get a more useful error message which will.... _tell you that it's a security error_

Comment: I fixed my issue based on this reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694601/sql-agent-job-failes-when-trying-to-execute-ssis-package-due-to-some-permission

Answer (score 1):

If it runs fine on your machine, but not fine on the server then perhaps this is a file access security issue?  It's possible that the account id associated with the SQL Server Agent Service does not have access to the folder where the attachment is held. Try adding that account to the folder.

You can find this account by navigating to `Windows Start \ Administrative Tools \ Services`, look for the service `SQL Server Agent ()` and find the user account listed under `Log On As`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code. It will help to know the error:

```
public void Main()
{
...
    try
    {
        ...
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
   {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ERROR", ex.Message, null, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

Even you can go for debugger to get more detail for the error you are facing.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions, and I'm going to try it myself, and then update here.